# How to I used or access the list inside the function to another function?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have this two functions:

```
lst = []
def function1(request):
    lst = ['12','10']
    return HttpResponse(...)

def function2(request):
    qry = SampleModel.objects.filter(id__in=lst)
    return HttpResponse(...)
```

Comment: global lst=[] outside of the functions

Comment: don't use global pass and return or use a class

Answer (score 0):

Use `global`. Here's one sample:

```
lst = [2,3]
def function1():
    global lst  # Guide lst to the global list that is already available
    print('lst = {}'.format(lst))
    lst = ['12','10']

print('lst = {}'.format(lst))
function1()
print('lst = {}'.format(lst))
```

You will see the following output:

```
lst = [2, 3]
lst = [2, 3]
lst = ['12', '10']
```

Answer (score -1):

**Check first example.**

```
global lst
lst=[]
def function1():

    lst.append(6)
    print(lst)

def function2():
    lst.append(7)
    print(lst)

function1()
function2()
```

**output:-**

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "C:/Users/akthakur/PycharmProjects/Learning python/testing.py"
[6]
[6, 7]
```

Here lst is declared as global and is used in function 1 and when used in function 2,same lst was used so the output.

**Second Example**

```
global lst
lst=[]
def function1():
    lst=[7,8]
    lst.append(6)
    print(lst)

def function2():
    lst.append(7)
    print(lst)

function1()
function2()
```

**Output**

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "C:/Users/akthakur/PycharmProjects/Learning python/testing.py"
[7, 8, 6]
[7]
```

Now as you defined in function1  **lst=[7,8]**  so this creates a new local  list lst and in function1 same was used(local version) and in function2 when you again called lst,its global version was called.[this is what you are doing.]

So rather then declaring new local list as **lst = ['12','10']** ,append your values to the existing list defined outside the function and declare the same as global.